# ordering by column by hebrew than english in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, hebrew

my table contains a column item_name that has these example values:

```
abba, babba, ארץ, חלב, כלב
```

those are english values and hebrew values.
I need a mysql query that will give me results ordered by hebrew value first (order by hebrew alphabet) - then the english values (ordered by english alphabet).

this is what i'm using now:

```
select id, item_name order by item_name
```

and it's giving me the english values first.

using UNION is a possibility using REGEXP...

Comment: Are the strings always either english or hebrew - so never a mixture of both? It might help to post up a sqlfiddle - assuming it can take multibyte characters.

Comment: just use "ORDER BY item_name"  and add DESC or ASC. DESC should give you Hebrew first. i should note that it is not recommended to put Hebrew and english values in the same column. בגלל העימוד

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use DESC or ASC order.
Try with 
select id, item_name order by item_name DESC
select id, item_name order by item_name ASC

Comment: no, add DESC or ASC will not do it.
it will get the hebrew first but it as I mentioned I need the hebrew sorted alphabetically.
and after those ordered alphabetically  i need the english ones sorted alphabatically.
adding ASC or DESC just reverses the initial order.

Answer (score 0):

The term that you are looking for is [collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-database.html). **Collation is the property which determines sorting order.** As you have found, the collations that MySQL ship with all sort ASCII characters before non-ASCII characters. The only way to handle that is to create your own collation, which is not a trivial undertaking.

Additionally, contrary to posted comments there is absolutely no problem in storing Hebrew and English values in the same field. Of course I recommend to store the data as UTF-8 in those cases.